# How to output a value on every third result of a foreach statement in php?

Tags: php, foreach, echo

I have a `foreach` statement in my app that echos a list of my database results:

```
<?php

foreach($featured_projects as $fp) {
  echo '<div class="result">';
  echo $fp['project_name'];
  echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

### I would like to:

On every third result, give the div a different class. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a counter and the [modulo/modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator as per below:

```
<?php

// control variable
$counter = 0;

foreach($featured_projects as $fp) {

    // reset the variable
    $class = '';

    // on every third result, set the variable value
    if(++$counter % 3 === 0) {
        $class = ' third';
    }

    // your code with the variable that holds the desirable CSS class name
    echo '<div class="result' . $class . '">';
    echo $fp['project_name'];
    echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php

foreach ($featured_projects as $i => $fp) {
    echo '<div class="result' . ($i % 3 === 0 ? ' third' : '') . '">';
    echo $fp['project_name'];
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Finally, somebody used a key instead of another variable and a ternary operator, nice and fast..

Answer (score 1):

If the `$featured_projects` array is based on incremental index you could simply use the index and the [modulo `%` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Otherwise you would have to add a counter.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 0):

add a counter in this loop and check if counter equals three and apply class.

Answer (score 0):

Using a counter and modulo operator this is easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

This is the working version, sorry for my prev version:

```
<?php
$featured_projects[0]['project_name'] = "pippo";
$featured_projects[1]['project_name'] = "pippo2";
$featured_projects[2]['project_name'] = "pippo3";

$class[0] = "class1";
$class[1] = "class2";

$i=0;
foreach($featured_projects as $fp) {
  $i++;
  if ($i == 3) {
    $c = $class[1];
    $i=0;
  } else {
    $c = $class[0];
  }
  echo "<div class=\"$c\">";
  echo $fp['project_name'];
  echo "</div>\n";
}
?>
```

Produces:

```
<div class="class1">pippo</div>
<div class="class1">pippo2</div>
<div class="class2">pippo3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter in loop ...try the following...

```
 <?php 
 $i = 0; 
 foreach($featured_projects as $fp) {
 $i = ++$i;
 if(($i%3) == 0)
 {
  $class1 = 'test1';
 }
 else
 {
 $class1 = 'test2';
 }
       echo '<div class="'.$class1.'">';
       echo $fp['project_name'];
       echo '</div>';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: @mr.blaff its jus a syntax error will come...but the logic is not wrong.without giving negative vote you can edit the answer...but you are keen on only giving negative vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
foreach($featured_projects as $fp) {
    if(++$i % 3 === 0) {
        $class = ' something';
    } else {
        $class = '';
    }
    echo '<div class="result' . $class . '">';
    echo $fp['project_name'];
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($featured_projects as $fp) {
    echo '<div class="'.($i++%3 ? 'result' : 'other_class').'">';
    echo $fp['project_name'];
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What leaves your code mostly in tact would be

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach($featured_projects as $fp) {
printf ('<div class="%s">',(($i % 3) ? "result" : "result_every_third" ));
echo $fp['project_name'];
echo '</div>';
$i++;
}
?>
```

But you may want to consider using a for or while construct around "each($featured_projects)" (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) which may result in neater code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;

    foreach ($featured_projects as $fp) {
        echo '<div class="result' . ($counter++ % 3 === 0 ? ' third' : '') . '">';
        echo $fp['project_name'];
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```